# Missing tab for ETW in Windows Device Portal

Tags: uwp, etw, windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to see event logs using ETW(Event tracing for Windows) for app running in one of my Windows phone. I tried to open the Windows Device portal using the steps mentioned here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal

But in the html page http://127.0.0.1:10080/default.htm (Since the phone was connected using LAN), I cannot see any section of ETW. Only Apps, Processes, Performance, Devices and Networking tabs are displayed.
Is there an additional setup file required? Or is there a Windows update required for accessing the same?

Comment: What's the OS version of your devices? This feature is added in Windows 10 Anniversary Update. Please make sure you have the latest OS Build.

Comment: you can write your own WPR profiles (.wprp) files and use FiledMedic to capture traces/ETW events.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT - Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, the phone was running on 10586 build.

Comment: Then you can update your phone to 14393 to use this feature. ;)

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT not all phones can be updates to 14393. The lumia x20 phones got Build 10586 via Insider but are not allowed to get 14393.

Answer (score 1):

**Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)** in [Windows Device Portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal) is newly added in Windows 10 Anniversary Update. To use this feature, please make sure your device uses the latest build of Windows (Version 1607 OS Build 14393 for now).

For more info, please see [Using Device Portal to view debug logs for UWP](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/10/using-device-portal-to-view-debug-logs-for-uwp/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [FiledMedic](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfjb82) instead to get ETW events. This App works for Windows 8.1 and all Windows 10 builds.

You'll have to create a [Windows Performance recorder Profile (.wprp)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448210.aspx). connect the phone to the PC via USB and store it under `This PC\Windows Phone\Phone\FieldMedic\CustomProfiles`

When now start the Field Medic App, go to `advanced` and here you find the new profile under `Custom Group`.

[image]

Select this and start logging.

[image]

Capture the activity of your app and go back to Fieldmedic, stop the logging and connect the Phone again to the PC navigate to `This PC\Windows Phone\Phone\FieldMedic\reports` and copy the ETL file to your PC and use [Perfview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2016/02/19/perfview-version-1-9-released-to-the-web/) or [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/introduction-to-the-wpa-user-interface) to analyze the ETL files to see your custom Events.

[image]